# Error recovery algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, checksum, error-checking

I am doing a software that grabs in the end a numeric string, that string encodes important data, and any error destroy the contents.

Worse: It is VERY prone for errors, because of how data is transmitted (and I can do nothing about it).

So I decided to add a verification digit of sorts... After some research, I have more questions than answers... So, someone can point me to a decent location to study more about that subject?

Also, someone know some popular algorithms that can even fix errors, or at least point where the errors are, so I can retry grabbing the data with error?

Also what I do, if the checksum data itself managed to be wrong in transmission?

Comment: What are constraints on the size?  Is the data transcribed by hand?  You can obviously trade space for reliability, for example an extremely naive error-correction scheme would be to simple re-transmit the code 100 times.  A good start for study is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction

Comment: the code has to fit a SMS (so, 140 characters...) also the data errors are not human errors at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Hamming Code](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/Networks/data.hamming.html)
- [simple pdf explanation of hamming code](http://www.cs.hartford.edu/~gray/cs451_S06/Hamming%20Code%20Project.pdf)

Basically for every N bits of your message, you have some check bits.

You can detect and correct errors in the check bits, based on the data, or errors in the data, based on check bits.  Too many errors though, and it's just garbage.  There may be a utility in your language of choice to already do this.

Answer (score 3):

This can be of use: http://www.eccpage.com/